# Prove that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n^2$ also converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n^2$  also converges.

**Attempt:**

$\sum |a_n|$ converges $\implies \sum |a_n|<M$.

If $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n $  also converges.

Could anyone please tell me on how to proceed ahead with regard to this problem.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: $\sum a_n^2 \le (\sum |a_n|)^2$,bounded monotone convergence thm

Comment: After a while $|a_n|\lt 1$, so $a_n^2\lt |a_n|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I just lost it all in this problem, I guess.

Comment: Note that $|a_n|$ must be bounded by some $M$ and so $|a_n|^2 \le M |a_n|$.

Answer (score 4):

Prove that there is a tail of the summation for which $a_n^2<|a_n|$ holds for all terms in the tail.